# What is the correct way of calculating MIPS?

Tags: instruction-set, cpu-cycles

I found below question about MIPS,

> A computer system has a CPU with a word length of 64 bits and a clock
> speed of
> 1.5GHz. For a certain task, the measured average CPI (cycles per instruction) of the processor is 0.6. What is the MIPS rate of the
> processor?

The given answer is,

> Instructions /second = cycles/second x instructions/cycles 
> = 1.5x10<sup>9</sup>x 1/0.6 
> = 2.5x10<sup>9</sup>/ 1 million 
> = 2500 MIPS

When I searched more examples, I found in most places the CPU speed was taken in Mhz (not as Hz) to calculate MIPS. Refer the below question & answer.

> Alternatively, divide the number of cycles per second (CPU) by the
> number of cycles per instruction (CPI) and then divide by 1 million to
> find the MIPS. For instance, if a computer with a CPU of 600 megahertz
> had a CPI of 3: 600/3 = 200; 200/1 million = 0.0002 MIPS.

But, if I solve the second one as solved the first one, the answer would be,

> = 600x10<sup>6</sup>x 1/3 
> = 200x10<sup>6</sup>/ 1 million 
> = 200 MIPS

What is the correct way of calculating MIPS?

Comment: Someone forgot the units in that 2nd example.  600 is already divided by 1 million, so that's dividing by 1 million twice.